# (Real) Analysis Book Recommendations (having already studied Abstract Algebra, Calculus 1-3, Linear Algebra)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking now to self-study (real) Analysis as it is one of the main pillars of modern mathematics, and a very useful requisite to many other complex theories and topics (e.g. topology, algebraic geometry, etc.) - and of course being interested in it! I have already studied Abstract Algebra (studied from Serge Lang Undergraduate Algebra), Calculus 1-3 (so therefore including multivariable and vector calculus), and Linear Algebra (with formal proofs). I find myself now quite comfortable with formal proofs, although apart from calculus I have no previous experience with Analysis. As I am self-studying, a good solution set is imperative also. I was thinking maybe of Rudin, Kolmogorov, Serge Lang Undergraduate Analysis, etc.? Anyway, all recommendations of books for Analysis very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Some suggestions here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2409501/343280

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Books for real analysis covering some specific topics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409478/books-for-real-analysis-covering-some-specific-topics)

Answer (score 1):

Big fan of Strichartz' Way of Analysis and Abbott's Understanding Analysis for self-study.

Comment: I second Abbott